# Windows phone - C# - link to buy app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.8

How can you implement a 'buy' link into a trial app?

Do you use the same method as for implementing a 'rate' link?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `MarketplaceDetailTask` launcher:

```cs
MarketplaceDetailTask marketplaceDetailTask = new MarketplaceDetailTask();
marketplaceDetailTask.Show();
```

See:

[How to use the Marketplace detail task for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394017%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

first of all you will have to register that buy in your developer accound as in-app product and then use this ...

```
  public static LicenseInformation licenseInformation;

    if (!App.licenseInformation.ProductLicenses["productid"].IsActive)
             {
                    try
                    {
                        // The user doesn't own this feature, so 
                        // show the purchase dialog.
                        await CurrentApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync("productid", false);
                        // the in-app purchase was successful
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        // The in-app purchase was not completed because 
                        // an error occurred.
                    }
                }
                else
                {

                    // The user already owns this feature.
                }
            }
```

Comment: Is there any way just to redirect to the mark place app page?

Comment: yes 
MarketplaceDetailTask marketplaceDetailTask = new MarketplaceDetailTask();
marketplaceDetailTask.Show();

Comment: I think This code is for In App Purchases. Newbie is asking how to show the marketplace page of the app to buy from a trial version